# How is automation of ETL processing done?

Tags: etl

I am alloted 'Automation of ETL processing using Scripting Technologies' as my Engineering Final Year project. However I don't have any idea about exactly what is this project supposed to do. I konw the basic concepts of ETL. But can anyone help me about what is meant by automation of these processes.
I am not asking for the implemetation. Just an overview of what needs to be done

Comment: If you are looking to automate the scheduled run of ETL process then you can use Shell or Python Scripting. In terms of Informatica, Workflows and Tasks can be started using PMCMD commands there are several others. If you can elaborate the title of your project it can be more helpful for people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean automation of initialization, it could be done by one of several things: You could kick off the process with the task scheduler, you could have a folder watcher that starts a process when it find a file in the folder it's watching, you could have a switch that watches an object's name an when the name is "on" it knows to run and rename the object to "off" when it's done, or it could be kicked off by a database trigger, etc.  Or are we talking about using the scripts to automate the steps necessary to complete the ETL?  Sounds like you need to talk to the prof.

Answer (score 0):

ETL tools generally have schedulers
and OS's have schedulers 
 ie Unix with contrab

all ETL processes should be idempotent.